# Retrieve values from two tables based on a third SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables(Table A(ID, PersonID), Table B(ID, PersonID), and Table C(PersonID)).  What I want to do is get all of the records that are in Table A that aren't in Table B, and the records from that set have to have the same PersonID from Table C.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table A]
UNION 
SELECT * FROM  [Table B]
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM [Table A]
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM [Table B]
```

The following query will get me the first condition, however; I'm unsure how to make the relation to Table C.  I don't think I can do an regular JOIN to accomplish this.

Comment: Wouldn't `(NOT) EXISTS` make more sense?

Comment: @ThomA I've been off the SQL scene for a while. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: [EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Is the table structure of `[Table A]` and `[Table B]` identical? Typically I would use `(not) exists` (just like @ThomA mentioned) based on specific fields that define what "existence" means. Set operations like you have there do work, but only if the sets are identically structured. If you can provide some sample data to play with and the expected output would make coming up with a solution easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused on your demo and the words to describe what you want.

But as long as that query is doing what you want, and it's results must also by in table c, then the following would work. The inner join will ensure that results found in set are in table c.

Test Setup

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_a') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_a
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_b') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_b
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_c') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_c

CREATE TABLE #tmp_a(ID int identity(1,1), PersonID int)
CREATE TABLE #tmp_b(ID int identity(1,1), PersonID int)
CREATE TABLE #tmp_c(PersonID int )

insert into #tmp_a
values 
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (7) -- not in B

insert into #tmp_b
values 
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6) -- not in A

insert into #tmp_c
values 
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6),
    (7)
```

Query

```
SELECT subset.*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM #tmp_a
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM  #tmp_b
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * FROM #tmp_a
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM #tmp_b
) subset
JOIN #tmp_c c on c.PersonID = subset.PersonID
```